# Why are there no fish korbanot?

Tags: animals, korban, fish

Land animals, birds, wheat and fruit offerings all feature on the list of offerings that Bnei Israel bring for Hashem.

Is there anyone that discusses why there are no fish korbanot?

Comment: What about locusts?

Comment: @DoubleAA Indeed!

Comment: Possibly because they are not specifically mentioned as being "allowed" after the flood? Combine that with Rav Kook's A Vision of Vegetarianism and Peace which cites the opinion that the 3rd temple won't have any animal sacrifices.

Comment: Note that it's only *domesticated* land animals that are brought as offerings (בהמות). Wild animals (חיות), like deer, are not. The birds that are brought are also domesticated species (doves), and wheat is a domesticated grain. It stands to reason that all fish could have been excused on these grounds too, there being no species that might have been considered anything but wild.

Comment: @DoubleAA No locusts for a very simple reason: Locusts are considered a curse. The Mishna in Brachot mentions that there is no bracha for something that is a curse with an example of locusts. And would it be proper to offer something that is considered a curse as a sacred offering?

Comment: @AvramLevitt Turning a curse into a blessing sounds like a good idea to me. Can you cite this Mishna?

Comment: @DoubleAA http://mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h11.htm Mishnah 6:3. The gemara clarifies that the Chachamim disagree (and the halacha is according to the Chachamim). But keep also in mind that locusts could not be factored into any sort of regular occasion (such as a korban) because it is not a predictable thing.

Comment: Maybe because they were not kept and raised domestically?

Comment: @DoubleAA the midrash in the below answer seems to answer your question, as insects are not flesh and blood like humans.

Comment: @BabySeal Yes.................

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The Midrash Tanchuma ([Vayikra 1:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Vayikra.8.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) asks your question:

> ולמה קריבין קרבן מן העוף ומן הכבשים ומן הצאן ומן העזים ולא מן הדגים, שנאמר, [ו] אם מן העוף עולה קרבנו, אלא בשביל שהם בשר ודם כמו האדם ויוצאין מבטן אמן כמו האדם, מכפרים על האדם. אבל הדגים, ביצים הם ויוצאין מהן וחיין.
>
> And why do we offer up sacrifices from birds, sheep and goats but not from fish?
>
> Because they (animals and birds) resemble man as they are born from the stomach of their mother like man. Thus, they atone for man. Fish, however, are eggs, that they emerge from and live.

I do have a *pshat* as to what this means (obviously birds come from eggs, too), but I'll have to add this in later..

Comment: We see birds lay eggs. Fish eggs are generated spontaneously?

Comment: Fish eggs, mice, what isn't?

Comment: how much time do fish eggs spend in the mother fish's belly?

Comment: Fish generally lay eggs which are then fertilized by the male outside of the mother. Birds generally lay eggs after they are fertilized inside the mother

Comment: birds - https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081228132023AAXhe5o

Comment: fish - https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090607184656AAdL0SP

Comment: Is it later yet?

Comment: still no explanation of this midrash?

Comment: @user9953 2nd'ed

Answer (score 2):

In the journal [*Dialogue*, vol. 5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1680250019), there's an extensive article by **Rabbi Eytan Feiner** titled "Aquatic Perfection: The Fascinating World of Fish and Water," where Rabbi Feiner suggests that fish are from a realm which does not require further perfection [which may also explain why fish do not require shechitah].

He also refers to the **(pseudo-)*Hiddushei ha-Ran***, Shabbat 108a:

> כשבא נחש על חוה הטיל זוהמא עלי' ועל כל בריות שבעולם, ישראל שעמדו על הר סיני נפסקה זוהמא מהם ומן הבריות שהיו שם **חוץ מדגים שלא היו שם**.

Comment: @user9953 maybe you can contact him directly

Answer (score 1):

The Ramban says the reason why their are no chicken Korbanos is because chickens are promiscuous. Seemingly, the same answer would apply to fish who mate frequently. (See also Kli Yakar, Parshas Behaloscha on Basar)

Comment: please cite source of Ramban

Comment: Chickens are different from fish in that many fish don't mate per se. They reproduce via external fertilisation, its hard to draw comparisons of promiscuity regarding chickens.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the temple in Jerusalem as well as other early Israelite temples (Beit El, Shilo, Sechem, etc.) are all at least a couple of days travel away from a source of live fish, it should not be very surprising that fish sacrifice did not become common.